# Interior Uniqueness: Does there exist an analytic function on a neighborhood of $z=0$ that satisfies the following?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analyticity, analytic-functions

I am faced with the following problem:

> Does there exist a function that is analytic on a neighborhood of $z=0$ and satisfies the following condition for every positive $n$:
>
> (a) $f(1/n)=f(-1/n)=1/n^{2}$ (I was given the hint that the answer is yes)
>
> (b) $f(1/n)=f(-1/n)=1/n^{3}$ (I was given the hint that the answer is no)

However, I have absolutely no idea how to even get started. I know I'm supposed to use the interior uniqueness theorem, but exactly how to use it is baffling me a bit. Perhaps if someone could tell me how to do part (a), I could use it to help me figure out part (b).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the question $a$, it is clear that $$f(z) = z^2$$ is a solution to the problem. A more difficult problem is to show that this solution is unique but it is not asked. However I will give you the hint to prove that and it will be helpful for the second exercice.

Suppose, there is another function $g$ holomorphic on a neighborhood $V$ of $0$ such that $$g(1/n)=f(1/n)=1/n^2$$ then taking the limit $n \to +\infty$, we find by continuity that $g(0)=f(0).$ Hence $f=g$ on the set $$\left\{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} \cup \{0\}.$$ In this set $0$ is a limit point so by the uniqueness theorem you find that $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z\in V$.

Comment: what do you mean "not isolated"? If you mean "isolated points", we haven't studied those yet.

Comment: What is the statement of the uniqueness theorem in your book ?

Comment: Suppose two functions analytic on a domain $G$ coincide on a set that has a limit point in $G$. Then, $f$ and $g$ coincide on the whole domain $G$.

Comment: Ok I edit my post to fit with that.

Comment: thank you. I'm going to look this over while on the train this morning, and try to figure out (b) based on what you told me. If I have any more questions, I'll be back.

Comment: @C.Debussy, let me know if this is ok: consider $g(z)=z^{3}$ which has the desired property of being analytic on a neighborhood of $0$ such that $g\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n^{3}}$. Then, taking the limit as $n \to \infty$, we find by continuity that $g(0)=f(0)$. So, $f=g$ on the set $\left \{\frac{1}{n}\right\}\cup \{0\}$. By uniqueness, then, we need $f(z)=z^{3}$, but $f(-1)=1\neq (-1)^{3}=-1$. So, by uniqueness, no such function exists.

Comment: Absolutely right. :)